# Return data from URL with Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I want to read stock data into a pandas dataframe. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338608/download-all-stock-symbol-list-of-a-market) question roughly matches what I want to do, but it recommends web scraping. I don't want to rely on web scraping to get my data, as I might need to rewrite my scraper if the website is redesigned.

How can I get the data from [this website](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download) into a pandas dataframe without web scraping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the url to [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
import  pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download")

print(df)
```

Comment: well now, that was easy. Thank you, Padraic.